Permission based access control using Entra ID with ASP.NET core
I'm designing a permissioning system for a new ser of services that my team is creating.
It is the first time that I'm doing this with a client who is using Entra ID for their authorization management. In the past I have dealt with clients where this was managed using hand rolled UIs.
I want the system to be Permission Based Access Control rather than Role Based Access Control.
Consider a scenario where I have the trader.senior and trader.junior roles. I have already created these as App Roles against my application in EntraId, and assinged them to my test users. However this requires me to securing my /executeTrade endpoint with an [Authorize(Roles = "trader.senior, trader.junior")].
I want to be able to do [MyCustomAuthorizaion(permission = "trade.execute"]. This means I need to create a permission called trade.execute and assign that permission to both the trader.senior and trader.junior role.
However, I have not been able to figure out how to set this up on Entra ID. Is it not possible, or am I simply looking in the wrong place? Should I be taking a different approach entirely?
Alternate approaches I have considered:

Use Entra Groups for my permissioning. This would enable me to have Senior Trader and Junior Trader groups, and a trade.execute role. Then I can assign the trade.execute role to the aforementioned groups, and assign users to the groups.
Create a custom layer wheryby I can manage the which permissions belong to which role. This would require an additional data store (for the role-permission) mapping, screens to manage that store, and querying the store with every (assuming no caching) request.


So did you create app roles?

yes - i mention this in my question

Unfortunately, Entra ID does not natively support permission-based access control in the way you described, where permissions are directly assigned to roles. You will need to implement a custom solution to achieve this functionality.

Thanks @rukmini, that was my suspicion as well.

Can I post an answer:)

Thank you for teaching me how stackoverflow works. After a decade log career I hadn't learned yet. I haven't accepted the answer yet incase a different (potentially better) solution presents itself.


Note that: Microsoft Entra ID does not support permission-based access control in the way you described, where permissions are directly assigned to roles. You will need to implement a custom solution to achieve this functionality.


Build a custom layer to manage the mapping of roles to specific permissions.

Otherwise as mentioned by you, you can make use of Entra Groups to manage permissions:

Create groups like Senior Trader and Junior Trader
And assign a role to these groups.
This will allow you to manage permissions at the group level, which can be simpler than handling individual role-permission mappings.

Create a group:

Create the app roles in the Microsoft Entra ID application based on your requirement:

And assign the roles to the groups in the Enterprise application:


